# Codeigniter 500 internal server error due to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, internal-server-error

I am working with codeigniter framework, and as I upload it to a host, it gave me a 500 Internal error.

But when I add `index.php` to `config.php` , it worked.

What should I do?

In my .htaccess I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /ci-framework/
```

And also when I clean `/ci-framework/` from end of RewriteBase it doesn't work.

Thank you very much.

Comment: make sure your wamp rewrite_modue is on..

in APACHE > APACHE Modules > rewrite_module

Comment: @HardikRanpariya I just cleaned `RewriteBase /ci-framework/` and it works. Any way Thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to add `index.php` in `config.php` file.
Make sure you have following line in `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On  
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: adding <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> in begining and closing with </IfModule> worked for me. :-)